How does the wing-tail interaction reduce drag at supersonic speed?
NASA report: "Effects of wing and tail location on the aerodynamic characteristics of an airplane for Mach numbers from 0.25 to 4.63" states that the drag coefficient at zero lift ($C_{d_0}$) is lower when the horizontal tail is close to the wing's trailing edge than when there is no horizontal tail:

An interesting effect of the tail on the drag characteristicsdoes occur. Although the addition of the tail in either the mid- or aft-axial positions causes an increase in CD.o, the forward tail position results in CD,o values slightly less than those for _he tail-off case. This drag reduction occurs since the forward tail is immediately aft of the wing and results in a decrease in wing trailing-edge drag as well as tail leading-edge drag. This reduction in drag coupled with the increased lift results in the forward coplanar tail configuration having the highest values of maximum L/D.

The reason for this drag reduction is that when the horizontal tail is close to the trailing edge of the wing, the trailing edge of the wing reduces the drag of the leading edge of the horizontal tail, and the leading edge of the horizontal tail reduces the drag of the trailing edge of the wing.
Since the $C_{d_0}$ at supersonic speed includes wave, friction, and pressure drag, how does this mutual effect of horizontal tail and wing on each other happen?
From the same document:


One might compare results to a pure delta, or perhaps a reverse swept trailing edge.

@RobertDiGiovanni no the whole report is just about that two configurations compared to horizontal tail off

Identifying the technical report would be great.  Also, it would be good to know the Mach number tested.  Are the leading edges of this configuration supersonic or subsonic at the test condition?  If they are supersonic, one might observe that the merged wing acts as a single wing and only has one set of shocks at the LE/TE vs. the split configuration has two sets.  Another thing to observe is that clearly the area distribution of the split configuration is worse and it will have higher wave drag.

@RobMcDonald https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19930089737/downloads/19930089737.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjiz-OBgI2JAxWEFlkFHTkNF5IQFnoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2BbTCCMt-9PNZg9TsyY-Bd

The images you posted are not in the document you linked to.

@RobMcDonald https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19830013883

@sophit https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19830013883

@alireza Thanks for the link.  Interestingly, the wing airfoil has a blunt TE, which can't be pretty, but probably sets up the horizontal tail well.  It looks like this could be explained either by area rule or sets of shocks approaches.  Interestingly, the drag benefit seems to occur across all Mach numbers.

Yes, i presume you're wondering why there can be lower drag with the tail on.  Did it occur to you that a reverse sweep on the trailing edge (of tail forward and/or solid one piece) may produce even less drag?

It would be nice to have those experiments backed up by CFD simulations in order to actually see how the airflow looks like but I suppose that what is at work there is quite simply the area-ruling: the configuration with the tailplane attached to the wing has a sectional area better distributed than the configuration with an aft tailplane and therefore a lower wave drag.
